# Assistance with idempotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents

I am taking linear algebra for the first time and am struggling with the concept of idempotent matrices. I know that $A = A^2$ is the concept behind it, but I can't seem to understand HOW one would find the entries, and the explanations given confused me quite a lot. I was hoping someone could give me the gist of this concept and point me in the right direction.

For example, I am faced with the question of "Find all $2\times 2$ matrices such that $A^2=A$"

Currently, I know that with the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ that:

$a = a^2 + bc\\
b = ab + bd\\
c = ca + cd\\
d = bc + d^2$

but I'm now unsure of how to determine entries off of that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How one would find the values of what? Which explanations confused you? Could you please try to clarify what exactly it is your struggling with?

Comment: Apologies, I tried to make my question clearer. I wish to know how to find all possible values of idempotent matrices, in this case, a 2 x 2 one.

Comment: A definition of idempotent matrices would be helpful. Also, the notation [a,b] is unclear, are a and b column vectors?

Comment: An idempotent matrice is when a matrice multiplied by itself will result in itself. Basically, A * A = A.

Comment: By values, do you mean the entries, $a,b,c,d$ of the matrix? If so, I don't think I've ever heard anyone refer to them as "values". This might be worth clarifying.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I meant the entries, like the numbers you would put in so that A * A = A.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, so you're not going to be able to just find them all explicitly.  Instead you can try solving for some of the variables in terms of others.

Comment: I see, I kind of figured that that was the case. What do you mean by that? Like, how would I solve some of the variables?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, multiply by the inverse of $A$ and conclude that $A$ must be $I$. If $A$ is not invertible, one row of $A$ must be a constant multiple of the other, which narrows the possibilities.

Comment: (A = A^-1 * A^2 = A^-1 * A = I) or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the system
$$a = a^2 + bc \tag{1}$$
$$b = ab + bd \tag{2}$$
$$c = ca + cd \tag{3}$$
$$d = bc + d^2 \tag{4}$$
Then, $(1) - (4)$ produces
$$a - d = a^2 - d^2 = (a - d)(a + d),$$
so $a = d$ or $a + d = 1$.

Assume, as one possible case, $a + d = 1$. Note that this implies $(2)$ and $(3)$ are automatically satisfied. As expected, if you substitute $d = 1 - a$ into $(4)$, you just get back $(1)$, so we now have only two equations (in this case):
\begin{align*}
bc &= a - a^2 \\
d &= 1 - a.
\end{align*}
We should let $a$ be a free variable; no matter what value $a$ takes, there will always be a solution, from which we can uniquely determine $d$. If $a - a^2 \neq 0$, then we can also let $b$ be a free variable, with the caveat that $b \neq 0$, and $c = \frac{a - a^2}{b}$. This produces a family of solutions:
$$\fbox{$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
\frac{a - a^2}{b} & 1 - a
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad a, b \in \Bbb{R}, \quad b \neq 0$}.$$

If $a - a^2 = 0$, i.e. $a = 0$ or $a = 1$ (and $d = 1$ or $d = 0$ respectively), then we have to be more careful. We would have two cases: $b = 0$ or $c = 0$. This gives us four families of solutions (which, as you should verify, are all solutions:
$$\fbox{$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
c & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & b \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
c & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad b, c \in \Bbb{R}$}.$$

This exhausts all the cases where $a + d = 1$. Otherwise, $a = d$. Then $(2)$ becomes
$$b = 2ab$$
i.e. $b = 0$ or $a = d = \frac{1}{2}$. Since $a = d = \frac{1}{2}$ is covered by the $a + d = 1$ case, we dismiss it. So, we assume $b = 0$. Similar analysis of $(3)$ shows us that $c = 0$. Hence, $(1)$ and $(4)$, along with our assumption that $a = d$, tells us that $a = d = 0$ or $a = d = 1$. That is, we have just two remaining solutions:

$$\fbox{$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$},$$
i.e. the zero and identity matrices.

Comment: I see! This all makes sense to me. Just one last question: how would we input entries to prove this? For example, (4, -1)(12, -3) is an idempotent matrix.

Comment: @GeorgeInnit I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I've proven that all $2 \times 2$ idempotent matrices have to fit into one of the above forms. I haven't really shown that every matrix in the above form is idempotent, but this is not difficult to show. If you want to show that these matrices are idempotent, or indeed the specific example you've come up with, it's as simple as squaring the matrix and verifying that you get the same result back.

Comment: Apologies if I sound confused, just trying to understand. What would a matrix in the above form look like? I'm just making sure I have this down correctly.

Comment: Well, it would look like one of those matrices, for specific $a$, $b$, and $c$. You found one of them, in the form of the matrices in the first box (taking $a = 4$ and $b = -1$). Other examples would be$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ -5 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix},$$etc.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! One last thing, if you don't mind: how did you get a = d?

Comment: @GeorgeInnit If $a - d = (a + d)(a - d)$, then either $a - d = 0$ (note both sides would be $0$), or it's not. If it isn't $0$, then we can divide both sides by $a - d$ to get $a + d = 1$. So, there are two cases, and we have to consider both separately.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is $2\times2$, its rank can only be zero, one or two. If the rank is zero, then $A=0$ and it is idempotent; if $A$ is rank-two, it is nonsingular and hence $A^2=A$ if and only if $A=I_2$.

The only interesting case is $\operatorname{rank}(A)=1$. In this case $A=uv^T$ for some nonzero vectors $u$ and $v$. Thus $A^2=uv^Tuv^T=u(v^Tu)v=(v^Tu)uv^T=(v^Tu)A$, and $A$ is idempotent iff $v^Tu=1$. (The quantity $v^Tu$ is actually the trace of $A$.) Let $u=(x,w)^T$ and $v=(y,z)^T$. Then $v^Tu=xy+zw$ and
$$
A=uv^T=\pmatrix{xy&xz\\ wy&wz}.
$$
Now there are two mutually exclusive scenarios:

- If $w=0$, then $v^Tu=1$ iff $xy=1$. Hence $x\ne0$ and $A=\pmatrix{1&xz\\ 0&0}$. Since $z$ is not constrained, $A$ can be parametrised as $\pmatrix{1&b\\ 0&0}$ where $b$ is arbitrary.
- If $w\ne0$, by scaling $u$ and $v$ by $\frac{1}{w}$ and $w$ respectively, we may assume that $w=1$. Thus $v^Tu=1$ iff $z=1-xy$. Hence $A$ can be parametrised as $\pmatrix{xy&x(1-xy)\\ y&1-xy}$, where $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary.

In summary, $A$ is idempotent if and only if it is in one of the following four forms:
$$
0,\quad I_2,\quad \pmatrix{1&b\\ 0&0},\quad\pmatrix{xy&x(1-xy)\\ y&1-xy}.
$$
Note that unlike the other answers, our parametrisation here is more parsimonious and it uses only multiplication but not division.

Answer (score 1):

The other solution is nice and explicit. Allow me to add a second solution that uses a bit more of the machinery that you will learn if not in this course on linear algebra then in the next. Maybe you will come back to this at that point.

From the idempotency equation $A^2 = A$, we see that $A$ is a zero of the polynomial $x^2 - x$ (i.e. if you substitute $A$ for $x$, you get the zero matrix). Therefore, the minimal polynomial $\mu_A$ divides $x^2 - x$. As $x^2 - x = x(x-1)$ (and the minimal polynomial can’t be $1$), it follows that $\mu_A = x$, $\mu_A = x - 1$ or $\mu_A = x(x-1)$.

For $2 \times 2$ matrices, this is enough to determine the Jordan normal form of $A$. Namely, $A$ must be similar to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
if $\mu_A = x$, similar to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
if $\mu_A=x-1$, and similar to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
if $\mu_A = x(1-x)$.

The first two matrices are only similar to themselves, so they’re two solutions. For the last, we need to conjugate with the general invertible $2 \times 2$ matrix,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $ad - bc \neq 0$ (because that is what it means to be “similar” to that matrix). This gives
$$
\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d & -b \\ -c & a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}-bc & -bd \\ ac & ad\end{pmatrix}.
$$
You can check that the matrix on the right is idempotent (whenever $ad-bc \neq 0$).